# displaying days of week in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am display days of week in my template, which I am declaring in my controller like

```
$scope.weekday = new Array(7);
        $scope.weekday[0]="Sunday";
        $scope.weekday[1]="Monday";
        $scope.weekday[2]="Tuesday";
        $scope.weekday[3]="Wednesday";
        $scope.weekday[4]="Thursday";
        $scope.weekday[5]="Friday";
        $scope.weekday[6]="Saturday";
```

As i am new to angular, would like to ask if it is OK or I can optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it better like this.

```
$scope.weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

Comment: that's about as optimum as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, using $local object:

```
$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.DAY
```